# How to set timeout to zero on the HTTP Get action of Tasker?

Tags: android, http-get, download, tasker

I have to download a file using Tasker, but the default timeout limit for the HTTP Get action (120 seconds) is not enough. How to set the timeout to zero (never) or to much more than 120 seconds? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

why is timeout of 120 seconds too short?

connection times out when time interval between estabilishing a connection and transmitting **any** data is too long

so if a download doesn't start within 2 minutes, connection will time out, to free the socket on the server.

//edit
alternatively, you can have a read on Keep-Alive request headers